# simple list in c++

Tags: c++

```
explicit list(
   const A& Al = A( )
);
explicit list(
   size_type n,
   const T& v = T( ),
   const A& Al = A( )
);
list(
   const list& x
);
list(
   const_iterator First,
   const_iterator Last,
   const A& Al = A( )
);
```

Comment: this code print each entry in turn - you just need the inner loop (without count < i). If you are looking for a general purpose way of random accessing a linked list - you cannot do it. use std::vector instead

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your edit.  Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <list>
using namespace std;

list<Node> my_list;

int index = 0;
for ( list<Node>::iterator cursor = my_list.begin();
    it!= my_list.end(); ++ cursor, ++ index ) {
    cout << "index: " << index << “ value: “ << cursor->data() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least based on what you have here, the problem isn't with how you traverse the list -- it's with using a list at all. You're asking for random access to the data, which means you should probably be using something like a vector or a deque instead of a list.

Comment: He implements random access in a sense, but only uses it to access elements in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I really can't tell what this is trying to do, but you have a possible segfault in your inner loop:

```
for ( cursor = head_ptr; cursor !=NULL ||count<i; cursor=cursor->link() )
{
count++;    
}
```

Your termination condition indicates that if `count < i`, you would keep looping even if `cursor == NULL`; when `cursor=cursor->link()` executes, you would try to dereference `NULL`.

Perhaps you meant `cursor !=NULL && count<i` ?